# Circle of Apollonius special case

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, geometric-construction

I am doubting how to prove this problem:

> Two circles intersect in the points $A$ and $B .$ A variable line through $A$ intersects the circles again in $P$ and $Q .$ If $R$ divides the segment $P Q$ in a given ratio, show that the locus of $R$ is a circle.

I did a construction in geogebra:

[image]

Should I just say that is it proved immediately from the circle of Apollonius theorem? It states:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does not follow from the theorem you cite: you don't have the "two fixed points".

Comment: Inversion around some circle centered in $A$ seems promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $O = (0,0)$, so that the equation of the first circle is $ p^T p = R_1^2 $, while the equation of the second circle is $(p - O')^T (p - O') = R_2^2 $.  Let the parametric equation of the variable line be

$ q = A + s u $ , where $u = [\cos \theta, \sin \theta]^T$, and $s \in \mathbb{R} $

Now we'll find points $P$ and $Q$.  $P$ is the intersection of the line with the first circle, so

$$(A + s u)^T (A + s u) = R_1^2 $$

since $A^T A = R_1^2$, then

$  2 s u^T A + s^2  = 0$

Therefore,

$ s = - 2 u^T A$

Thus, $ P = A - 2 (u^T A) u$

similarly for the second circle, we have,

$$  ( A - O' + s u )^T ( A - O' + s u ) = R_2^2$$

and since $(A - O')^T (A - O') = R_2^2 $ , then

$ s = - 2 u^T (A - O')$

Thus,

$Q = A - 2 u^T (A - O') u$

Assuming the fixed ratio $r = \dfrac{PR}{PQ}$, then

$\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
R &= P + r (Q - P) \\
  &= A - 2 (u^T A) u + r ( - 2 ) u^T ( A - O' - A ) u \\
  &= A - 2 (u^T A ) u + 2 r u^T (O') u \\
  &= A + 2 u^T (r O' - A) u  \\
\end{split} 
\end{equation}$

Now assume that $r O' - A = v = [v_1, v_2]^T $, then

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
R &= A + 2 ( v_1 \cos \theta + v_2 \sin \theta ) [ \cos \theta, \sin \theta]^T \\
   &= A + 2 [ v_1 \cos^2 \theta + v_2 \sin \theta \cos \theta , v_1 \cos \theta \sin \theta + v_2 \sin^2 \theta ]^T \\
&= A +  [  v_1 (1 + \cos 2 \theta) + v_2 \sin 2 \theta , v_1 \sin 2 \theta + v_2 (1 - \cos 2 \theta ) ^T \\
&= A + [v_1, v_2]^T + \cos 2 \theta [v_1, -v_2]^T + \sin 2 \theta [ v_2, v_1 ]^T 
\end{split} \end{equation} $

Since the vectors $[v_1, -v_2]^T$ and $[v_2, v_1]^T$ are orthogonal and of equal length, then this is clearly the equation of a circle with center $A + [v_1 , v_2]^T $ and radius $R = \sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2 } = \| r O' - A \| $

Comment: It's a great proof! However I was looking for a synthetic proof without advanced concepts. Anyway, I'll mark the question as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for posting the problem.  I enjoyed solving it.